# Worker thread doesn't have message loop (MFC, windows). Can we make it to receive messages?

Tags: multithreading, visual-c++, mfc

Mfc provides both worker and UI thread. UI thread is enabled with message receiving capabilities (send, post). Could it be possible to let worker thread too receive messages.

Comment: Why not use a UI thread then? Regardless of the name, you don't have to include any UI stuff. In fact, people who know better than I do recommend putting all the UI stuff in the main thread, so a UI thread would be a "secondary thread with message pump".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need a thread, that can handle multiple messages from another threads. Another threads would add-a-message to the message-queue of this thread. Well, in that case you may use `PeekMessage` to startup a loop, which would eventually create a hidden window, and then use `GetMessage` to get the messages. The other threads would use `PostThreadMessage` with the thread ID  (the one having Peek/GetMessage), and the message-code, `LPARAM`, `WPARAM.`

It would be like (not syntactically correct):

```
TheProcessor()
{
    MSG msg;
    PeekMessage(&msg,...);

    while(GetMessage(&msg...)
    {    /* switch case here */ }
}
```

The threads would call `PostThreadMessage` - See MSDN for more info.
When you need to send more data than LPARAM/WPARAM can hold, you eventually need to allocate them on heap, and then delete AFTER processing the message in your custom message-loop. This would be cumbersome and buggy.

But... I would suggest you to have your own class, on top of `std::queue/deque` or other DS, where you can add `AddMessage`/`PushMessage`, and `PopMessage` (or whatever names you like). You need to use `SetEvent`, `WaitForSingleObject` to trigger the new message in loop (See one of the [implementation here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/MultiThreadSimpleQueue.aspx). You may make it generic for one data-type, or make it template class - that would support any data-type (your underlying DS (`queue`) would utilize the same data-type). You also need not to worry about heaps and deletions. This is less error prone. You may however, have to handle MT issues.

Using Windows events involves kernel mode transition (since events are named/kernel objects), and you may like to use Conditional Variables which are user objects.Or you may straightaway use `unbounded_buffer` class from Concurrency Runtime Library available in VC10. See [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/Parallel_Programming/parallelcpp.aspx) (jump to `unbounded_buffer`).

Answer (score 2):

Call `CWinThread::PumpMessage()` repeatedly until it returns a `WM_QUIT` message.

Comment: How would you send message ? sendmessage/postmessage requires handle to window. I believe postthreadmessage will do the things.GetMessage can do the things.

Comment: You can pass a reference to your CThread Object to ::PostThreadMessage() or you can call CThread::PostThreadMessage(). SendMessage() cannot be used to send a message to another thread. PostThreadMessage() only puts the message in a queue. You can not know how or when the correspondig action was completed, because the thread handles the message asynchroniously.

Comment: You will regret attempting to post messages to queues without a window to dispatch it to. Create a hidden window to be the recipient of these messages.

Comment: If the window handle is NULL, isn't the message sent to the member function of the CWinThread derived class through it's message-map? Why address a window? CWinThread has the same base class as CWnd! Try CWinThread::PostMessage() with the MSG structure's hwnd field set to NULL.

Comment: In any case, never call CWnd::SendMessage() to a window from another thread. Things could get really messed up by that. The Debug versionof MFC will ASSERT.

Comment: Thanks, comments have answered my question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can create a message queue on a worker thread. You will need to run a message pump on that thread.

Comment: GetMessage can do the things.