# How to create a modeless dialog from a worker thread when main GUI thread is blocked?

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, mfc, dialog

My goal is to write a class (let's call it `CProgressDlg`) that can be used to display a dialog window with a progress bar when some operation in the main UI thread takes longer than, say 1 second, to finish. So a previously written method:

```
if(do_work)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < a_lot; i++)
    {
        //Do work...
        ::Sleep(100);     //Use sleep to simulate work
    }
}
```

can be easily adjusted as something like this (pseudo-code):

```
if(do_work)
{
    CProgressDlg m_progDlg;

    for(int i = 0; i < a_lot; i++)
    {
        //Do work...
        ::Sleep(100);     //Use sleep to simulate work

        if(m_progDlg.UpdateWithProgress(i))
        {
            //User canceled it
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

So to implement it I would start a worker thread from the `CProgressDlg` constructor:

```
::CreateThread(0, 0, ThreadProcProgressDlg, (LPVOID)0, 0, 0);
```

And then from a worker thread I would create a modeless dialog that will display the progress bar and a cancel button for the user:

```
DWORD WINAPI ThreadProcProgressDlg(
  _In_ LPVOID lpParameter
)
{
    //Wait a little
    ::Sleep(1000);

    HMODULE hModule = AfxGetResourceHandle();
    ASSERT(hModule);

    //Get parent window
    //(Can't use main window, as its UI thread is blocked)
    HWND hParentWnd = NULL;

    const static BYTE dlgTemplate[224] = {
        0x1, 0x0, 0xff, 0xff, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc8, 0x0, 0xc8, 0x90, 0x4, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xdb, 0x0, 0x4b, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x8, 0x0, 0x90, 0x1, 0x0, 0x1, 0x4d, 0x0, 0x53, 0x0, 0x20, 0x0, 0x53, 0x0, 0x68, 0x0, 0x65, 0x0, 0x6c, 0x0, 0x6c, 0x0, 0x20, 0x0, 0x44, 0x0, 0x6c, 0x0, 0x67, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 
        0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x1, 0x0, 0x1, 0x50, 0x92, 0x0, 0x36, 0x0, 0x42, 0x0, 0xe, 0x0, 0x2, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xff, 0xff, 0x80, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x81, 0x0, 0x2, 0x50, 0x7, 0x0, 0x7, 0x0, 0xcd, 0x0, 0x19, 0x0, 0xed, 0x3, 0x0, 0x0, 0xff, 0xff, 0x82, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 
        0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x80, 0x50, 0x7, 0x0, 0x21, 0x0, 0xcd, 0x0, 0x7, 0x0, 0xec, 0x3, 0x0, 0x0, 0x6d, 0x0, 0x73, 0x0, 0x63, 0x0, 0x74, 0x0, 0x6c, 0x0, 0x73, 0x0, 0x5f, 0x0, 0x70, 0x0, 0x72, 0x0, 0x6f, 0x0, 0x67, 0x0, 0x72, 0x0, 0x65, 0x0, 0x73, 0x0, 0x73, 0x0, 0x33, 0x0, 0x32, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 
        0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x81, 0x0, 0x2, 0x50, 0x7, 0x0, 0x29, 0x0, 0xcd, 0x0, 0x8, 0x0, 0xee, 0x3, 0x0, 0x0, 0xff, 0xff, 0x82, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, };

    //Show dialog
    HWND hDlgWnd = ::CreateDialogIndirectParam(hModule, (LPCDLGTEMPLATE)dlgTemplate, hParentWnd, DlgWndProc, (LPARAM)0);
    ASSERT(hDlgWnd);
    if(hDlgWnd)
    {
        ::ShowWindow(hDlgWnd, SW_SHOW);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Where the minimal dialog procedure (just to display it) will be something like this:

```
INT_PTR CALLBACK DlgWndProc(HWND hDlg, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(wParam);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lParam);

    switch (uMsg)
    {
        case WM_INITDIALOG:
        {
        }
        return TRUE;

        case WM_COMMAND:
        {
            UINT uCmd = LOWORD(wParam);

            if (uCmd == IDOK || 
                uCmd == IDCANCEL)
            {
                ::DestroyWindow(hDlg);

                return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
            }
        }
        break;
    }

    return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
}
```

But when I run this code, my modeless dialog is shown for a split second and then disappears. I understand that I probably haven't done something to display it properly from a worker thread.

Any idea what am I missing?

Comment: Why do you give the heavy work to the GUI thread and the progress bar to the worker thread? Shouldn't it be the other way round?

Comment: @Alex: I understand that. Like I said, this a patch for the code that was already written.

Comment: Example: a user clicks on the list column to sort it (a list with a lot of items). In the current code it may block the main thread for about 5 seconds with a spinning mouse cursor. I was thinking to write this class to address situations like that. (It's just one example that comes to mind.)

Comment: Maybe there's a bug that causes the destroy function to be called unintentionally? Does stepping through the code via debug breakpoints leave any clues?

Comment: @Alex: yes, `WM_INITDIALOG` is called once but `WM_COMMAND` is never called. It's something about creating that dialog from a worker thread. If I call it from the main UI thread, everything works fine.

Comment: "So to implement it I would start a worker thread from the CProgressDlg constructor" Starting threads from a constructor is something that caused me problems in the past, because those threads tend to want to access functions from unfinished objects, but not sure if it's a problem in your case.

Comment: Is there a message loop running in that thread?

Comment: @Michael: No. I was thinking that that might be the reason. The code above is all I'm testing with. So how do I create it?

Comment: Since you're doing the heavy work in the main thread, then it doesn't make sense to create a worker thread for the sole purpose of updating the GUI. It will surely create more problems than solve. That said, if you need to update parts of the `GUI` from a worker thread, you're typically going to post a message using `PostMessage` and have the main thread process this message inside the heavy work loop. Again, this is no better than having the main thread do all the work (in fact, it's worse).

Answer (score 1):

For a thread to display a window, there must be a message loop so the window receives messages. Worker threads typically do not have message loops, so no window can be displayed. Otherwise, you need to call [GetMessage()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getmessage) periodically, a bad practise but it will anyway work. After you get a message, Use TranslateMessage() and DispatchMessage().

Also see [Worker thread doesn't have message loop (MFC, windows). Can we make it to receive messages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661645/worker-thread-doesnt-have-message-loop-mfc-windows-can-we-make-it-to-receiv)

Comment: Well, I can't call `GetMessage` or `PeekMessage` because I don't have a window for that worker thread. Plus `GetMessage` will block execution.

Comment: That is the point of GUI threads: to block until you have a message. And that is why it's bad to call it from a thread that is supposed to do other work.

Answer (score 1):

As others pointed out you cannot simply create windows from non GUI thread. Even if you were able to, you would still have a problem of main thread 'hanging' as you said.

Your have 2 solutions here: 
1) Use message pumping technique
2) Move the work into a thread and wait on GUI while showing progress window

Unfortunately both solutions require you to deal with this on case by case basis. You need to manually identify all potentially long operations on GUI and then modify their code.

In both cases I like to use modal dialog for progress bar control because modal dialog blocks access to main UI. This prevents user from interacting with other features until current one is completed.

1. The most basic way to prevent hanging is to add a function that peeks at message queue and pumps it:

```
bool CMyGUIWnd::PumpAppMessages()
{
    MSG msg;
    while (::PeekMessage (&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_NOREMOVE)) {
        if (!AfxGetApp ()->PumpMessage ()) {
            ::PostQuitMessage (0);
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

In any lengthy code (like your column sort) you would need to find places where to sprinkle this `PumpAppMessages` to keep program responsive.

Of course you don't want to call this all the time and you might want to make sure you only call it after certain number of milliseconds (250 in my example below):

```
bool CMyGUIWnd::PumpMessages()
{
    //
    // Retrieve and dispatch any waiting messages.
    //
    bool do_update = false;
    DWORD cur_time = ::GetTickCount ();

    if (cur_time < m_last_pump_message_time){
        do_update = true; // wrap around occurred
    }else{
        DWORD dt = cur_time - m_last_pump_message_time;
        if (dt > 250){
            do_update = true;
        }
    }

    if (do_update)
    {
        m_last_pump_message_time = cur_time;    
        return PumpAppMessages();
    }

    return true;
}
```

where `m_last_pump_message_time` is initialized with `::GetTickCount()`.

To show progress bar and block UI, you would need to write a progress dialog class which calls your lengthy function once it's created. You would instantiate this dialog before the function and block UI with `DoModal` call.

```
void CMyGUIWnd::LengthyCallWrapper()
{
    CProgressDlg dlg (&LengthyCall);
    dlg.DoModal();
}

void CMyGUIWnd::LengthyCall()
{
    // Long process with lots of PumpMessages calls to keep UI alive
}
```

2. The second approach is a bit more work, but makes the UI more responsive because it doesn't depend on how often message pumping is done.

You would again use the progress dialog class which takes the lengthy function pointer and executes it in worker thread. Once the thread is finished it should post a message to dialog. In response to this message the dialog would close itself unblocking UI.

For actual progress reporting in both cases your `LengthyCall` should take a pointer to the progress dialog so that it could update proper controls. In the second approach you would need to add sync objects like `CCriticalSection` when setting any progress variables but you would not modify any controls directly. Instead, you would setup a timer and check and update progress controls in regular intervals based on provided variables.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey, I appreciate your input.

Comment: But have you tried it? I've used both approaches in commercial software for at least 15 years now. As I said, there's no magic bullet when it comes to GUI thread on Windows. If you want to show progress for long task on GUI, you need to interrupt it, otherwise you move it to worker thread and and talk back to UI.

Comment: No, I haven't. I implemented it myself some time ago. I think I posted my solution somewhere in comments. Basically I create a message loop in my worker thread that allows to create its own popup window that lets a user see progress and cancel if needed. The main thread periodically calls an update function that notifies the worker thread of its progress, checks the `stopNow` event if it needs to quit and also  does this: `PeekMessage(&msg, hMainThreadWnd, 0, 0, PM_NOREMOVE);` to prevent GUI thread from showing "Not responding" in the title bar for the locked GUI thread.

Comment: I understand that this is not an ideal solution, as it doesn't allow GUI thread to process its drawing messages, which has a side effect of the main window becoming grayed out if the user starts heavily interacting with it. But, on a plus side, such approach can be included into already working code with just 2 or 3 lines of code without doing anything else. Thus I'm going with it.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> CreateDialogIndirectParam(...)
> ShowWindow(...)
> ```

`CreateDialog` returns immediately, the thread exits after `ShowWindow`, and so the mode-less dialog closes because the thread is finished.

This is different than `DialogBox`, `DialogBoxIndirect` which have their own message loop, and do not return until the dialog is closed by the user or another message.

The usage for `CreateDialog`, `CreateDialogIndirectParam`... is as follows:

```
CreateDialogIndirectParam(...)
ShowWindow(...)

MSG msg;
while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
{
    if(hDlgWnd == 0 || !IsDialogMessage(hDlgWnd, &msg))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
}
```

---

In this case you can just borrow a window from GUI thread. Example:

```
class CProgressDlg : public CDialog
{
public:
    bool stop;
    CProgressDlg() { stop = false; }
    void OnCancel()
    {
        stop = true;
        CDialog::OnCancel();
    }
};

UINT WorkerThread(LPVOID ptr)
{
    CProgressDlg* dlg = (CProgressDlg*)ptr;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Sleep(1000);
        if(dlg->stop)
        {
            dlg->MessageBox(L"stopped");
            break;
        }
    }

    dlg->SendMessage(WM_COMMAND, IDCANCEL);
    return 0;
}

void CMyWindow::foo()
{
    m_progress.Create(IDD_PROGRESS, this);
    m_progress.ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
    AfxBeginThread(WorkerThread, (LPVOID)&m_progress);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not that easy. What seemed to have happened is this. A modeless dialog uses the message loop of its parent window. Another stipulation seems to be that the parent window's `WndProc` must be in the same thread. So in my case when `CreateDialogIndirectParam` was called, it didn't find any message loop associated with the thread and thus some internal check made it self-destruct. The workaround was to create a message loop. Unfortunately it's easier said than done.

Comment: I basically ended up registering a custom class from a worker thread, then created a message-only window of that class and thus had it have its own message loop in that worker thread. Then, I could communicate with that thread using `SendMessage`/`PostMessage` mechanism from the main thread (prior to it going into a long processing.) Then using one of the custom `WM_APP+n` messages I was able to notify my thread to call `CreateDialogIndirectParam` as I showed above. But that still had some surprises in store associated with the fact that my main GUI thread's message loop was hanging ....

Comment: i.e. if I specified `HWND` of the "hanging" main thread as a parent window for either `CreateDialogIndirectParam` or `ShowWindow`, both functions would hang when trying to display my window until the main thread became responsive. (Thus defeating the purpose of my exercise here.) I guess both APIs communicate with the parent window using `SendMessage` of sorts. So the only way to display my modeless window was to use `NULL` as a parent, which unfortunately had its own negative consequence of dis-joining it from its parent window. Which I haven't overcome yet ...

Comment: The thread has finished and so the window associated with that thread is destroyed. You can't have a window that's associated with a thread which no longer exists; or a process which no longer exists.